# A question on a matrix built with permutations of the $n$ first integers.

Tags: matrices, permutations, matrix-equations

Let each row and each column of a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ be a permutation of $\{1, 2,...n\}$ and
let $A$ be symmetric.

(a) If $n$ is odd, prove that each of $1, 2,..., n$ occurs on the principle diagonal of $A$.

(b) For every even number $n$, show that there exists an $A$ in which not all of $1, 2,.... n$
appear on the diagonal.

Comment: Do you know what a permutation is?

Comment: Be careful, a permutation matrix is something different than what you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting the new title. I just came through this problem, I have never solved a problem of Matrix with permutation. So thought it may be Permutation Matrix

Comment: What you are describing are latin squares.

Comment: Yes, it is Latin Squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint(a):** Consider parity. Each integer must appear an odd number of times. Hence, it must appear on the diagonal.

**Hint(b):** Construct this yourself, it's not hard.

Comment: The parity argument is neat.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks (it's not original). This is a standard problem in the literature.